# Rails 3: How to trigger a form submission via javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that for the most part just submits as a normal form, so I don't want to set in the form_tag the :remote => true option.

However, under certain circumstances I'd like to be able have a javascript function post the form as if it had been posted by :remote => true. What would I need to do in javascript to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried this which definitely works, if the form has remote => true, just remove the data-remote attribute to submit normally w/ javascript ie

```
$('input').click(function(){ $('#form').removeAttr('data-remote') });
```

I'm guessing the opposite would probably work ie if the form doesn't have remote => true just do

```
$('input').click(function(){ $('#form').attr('data-remote',true)});
```

Answer (score 33):

I'm sorta new to this but here goes...

rails.js (the jquery one at least) defines the following function to catch and submit forms:

```
$('form').live('submit.rails', function(e) { ... });
```

If you use the following it should trigger the same function (and if :remote => true, then it wont cause a page reload):

```
$("#<yourformid>").trigger("submit.rails");
```

So, if you wanted to submit your form on a select change for example, you could set the above trigger call to the select's :onchange I would imagine.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking on "How to trigger a rails remote form submission with javascript"

Comment: I did this exactly, but it still is requesting HTML from the controller, not js, and as a result my respond_to do |format| format.js; end is giving an error.

Comment: I tried this and my form is still submitting traditionally, not remotely. Is that because I'm using Rails 5? Any framework updates here?

Comment: Yes, Rails 5.1 replaced jquery-ujs with a new rails-ujs library.  See my new answer for Rails 5.1+ :)

Answer (score 3):

maybe u could try this:

```
$('#form').submit();
```

Comment: That will submit the form normally, without triggering format.js.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery you could do something like this to have the form auto-post on keyup events, or simplify it to trigger manually:

```
  $(function() {    
    $("#live_search input").keyup(function() {
        q = $('#search_text').val();
      $.ajax({
          beforeSend      : function(request) { request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript"); },
                           // Included so Rails responds via "format.js"
          data          : 'query=' + q,
          success       : function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                                // alert(textStatus);
                                $("#live_search #results").html(data);
                                },
          error         : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                // alert(errorThrown);
                                $('#annotation_dialog').html(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                                },
          type            : 'POST',
          url                 : '/search/live'
      });
      return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5 (which replaces jquery-ujs with rails-ujs), this is how you trigger the handler rails attaches to a form's `submit` event:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('myform') // or $('#myform')[0] with jQuery
Rails.fire(elem, 'submit');
```

(Holy cow did it take me forever to figure that out!)