# Trigger Rails 3 AJAX "manually"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a small form that I want to submit through AJAX when a dropdown is changed. I have set the form to be :remote => true.

But if I do something like:

```
$('.element').change ->
    this.form.submit()
```

The form is not submitted through AJAX. Can I trigger Rails ajax submit function somehow instead of the .submit()?

Comment: Would it work using `this.form.onsubmit()`

Comment: No. onSubmit() is an event? I want to submit my form, but I want Rails to catch it and handle the AJAX. If I use this.form.submit() the form is submitted, but only as a normal request and not AJAX.

Comment: Are you using the jQuery UJS? Try this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4972151/590177

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm trying to do this in Active Admin which seems to not use the same JS as Rails default...