# Form submission via javascript in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found partial answer in [Rails 3: How to trigger a form submission via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904101/rails-3-how-to-trigger-a-form-submission-via-javascript)

I can trigger form submit with

```
$("#form_id").trigger("submit.rails");
```

But I can't find a way to pass some value to submit like I would send "back_button" to controller with

```
<%= f.submit "Back", class: "btn", :name => "back_button" %>
```

Is there a way to do this in javascript?

Comment: Do you want to submit the for upon changing some value?

Answer (score 1):

A day of googling and testing I found a working sollution. For those who may encounter the same problem here is the code:

```
var data = $("#my_form_id").serializeArray();
data.push({"name":"your_key_to_add_to_submit","value":"your_value"});

$.post("url_for_submit", $.param(data), null, "script");
```